# How do you access the Google Apps Marketplace UserLicense from Apps Script (for a Sheets add-on)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

I have a Sheets add-on for which I need to know the users license information from GAM (`appsmarket/v2/userLicense`). Since the user is already logged into Sheets, I wasn't expecting to need to use OAuth, but I'm getting a 403 (`"message":"Not authorized to access the application ID"`). Is there a way to access the license from Apps Script without using OAuth? Here is my code so far:

```
function testGetLicense(query) {
   var options = {
     'method' : 'get',
     'contentType': 'application/json',
     'muteHttpExceptions' : true
   };
  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/userLicense/1234/xxx@gmail.com'
  res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

If I need to use OAuth, should I be using this library?

https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the OAuth Token in the headers.

```
function testGetLicense(query) {
   var options = {
     'method' : 'get',
     'contentType': 'application/json',
      'headers': {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      },
     'muteHttpExceptions' : true
   };
  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/userLicense/1234/xxx@gmail.com'
  res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(res.getContentText())
}
```